# meaning of "as did a police officer"

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

> She had never had a husband or children, but a nephew visited her regularly, **as did a police officer**, and everyone in the neighbourhood liked her. My former classmate spoke of her with warmth and respect, and added that Emerence was a caretaker, someone with a bit of authority; she hoped the woman would take us on, because frankly, if she didn't warm to us, no amount of money would induce her to accept the job.

I get somehow confused to get its meaning!

Dose it mean: apart from her nephew a police officer visited her regularly too? 
Or Does it mean: her nephew is a police officer?

Source: "The door: the novel" by Magda Szabo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the first.

*... as did X ...* means *X did the same.*